# Why is my Open GL Compute Shader so slow?

Tags: opengl, glsl, compute-shader

I have been building an OpenGL compute shader that implements ray tracing. Currently it just computes the pixel color by casting a ray against an array of triangles.

```c
#version 430 core
struct Triangle {
 vec3 vertex1;
 vec3 vertex2;
 vec3 vertex3;
 vec3 color1;
 vec3 color2;
 vec3 color3;
 vec3 normal1;
 vec3 normal2;
 vec3 normal3;
 vec3 edge1;
 vec3 edge2;
};
layout (std430, binding = 0) readonly buffer TriangleBuffer {
 int numTriangles;
 Triangle triangles[];
};
layout (std430, binding = 1, column_major) buffer CameraBuffer {
 vec3 cameraPosition;
 mat4 view;
 mat4 projection;
 mat4 inverseViewProjection;
};
layout (rgba8, binding = 2) writeonly uniform image2D outputImage;
layout (local_size_x = 1, local_size_y = 1, local_size_z = 1) in;
vec3 getBarycentricCoords(int triangleIndex, vec3 closestIntersectionPoint) {
 vec3 v0 = triangles[triangleIndex].vertex2 - triangles[triangleIndex].vertex1;
 vec3 v1 = triangles[triangleIndex].vertex3 - triangles[triangleIndex].vertex1;
 vec3 v2 = closestIntersectionPoint - triangles[triangleIndex].vertex1;
 float d00 = dot(v0, v0);
 float d01 = dot(v0, v1);
 float d11 = dot(v1, v1);
 float d20 = dot(v2, v0);
 float d21 = dot(v2, v1);
 float denom = d00 * d11 - d01 * d01;
 float b1 = (d11 * d20 - d01 * d21) / denom;
 float b2 = (d00 * d21 - d01 * d20) / denom;
 float b0 = 1.0f - b1 - b2;
 return vec3(b0, b1, b2);
}
vec3 getTriangleColor(int triangleIndex, vec3 closestIntersectionPoint) {
 vec3 barycentric = getBarycentricCoords(triangleIndex, closestIntersectionPoint);
 vec3 triangleColor = barycentric.x * triangles[triangleIndex].color1 + barycentric.y * triangles[triangleIndex].color2 + barycentric.z * triangles[triangleIndex].color3;
 return triangleColor;
}
bool rayTriangleIntersection(vec3 rayOrigin, vec3 rayDirection, int triangleIndex, out vec3 intersectionPoint) {
 vec3 h = cross(rayDirection, triangles[triangleIndex].edge2);
 float a = dot(triangles[triangleIndex].edge1, h);
 if (a > -0.00001 && a < 0.00001) {
  return false;
 }
 float f = 1.0 / a;
 vec3 s = rayOrigin - triangles[triangleIndex].vertex1;
 float u = f * dot(s, h);
 if (u < 0.0 || u > 1.0) {
  return false;
 }
 vec3 q = cross(s, triangles[triangleIndex].edge1);
 float v = f * dot(rayDirection, q);
 if (v < 0.0 || u + v > 1.0) {
  return false;
 }
 float t = f * dot(triangles[triangleIndex].edge2, q);
 if (t > 0.00001) {
  intersectionPoint = rayOrigin + rayDirection * t;
  return true;
 }
 return false;
}
vec3 unProject(vec3 win, mat4 model, mat4 proj, vec4 viewport) {
 vec4 tmp = vec4(win, 1);
 tmp.x = (tmp.x - viewport[0]) / viewport[2];
 tmp.y = (tmp.y - viewport[1]) / viewport[3];
 tmp.x = tmp.x * 2 - 1;
 tmp.y = tmp.y * 2 - 1;
 vec4 obj = inverseViewProjection * tmp;
 obj /= obj.w;
 return obj.xyz;
}
void main() {
 ivec2 pixelCoord = ivec2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy);
 vec4 viewport = vec4(0, 0, vec2(imageSize(outputImage)).xy);
 vec3 near = vec3(pixelCoord.x, pixelCoord.y, -1);
 vec3 far = vec3(pixelCoord.x, pixelCoord.y, 0.9518f);
 vec3 rayOrigin = unProject(near, view, projection, viewport);
 vec3 rayWorldFar = unProject(far, view, projection, viewport);
 vec3 rayDirection = normalize(rayWorldFar - rayOrigin);
 vec3 intersectionPoint;
 vec3 closestIntersectionPoint = vec3(0,0,0);
 float closestIntersectionDistance = 999999999.0f;
 vec3 finalColor = vec3(0,0,0);
 bool intersectionFound = false;
 for (int triangleIndex = 0; triangleIndex < numTriangles; triangleIndex++) {
  if (rayTriangleIntersection(rayOrigin, rayDirection, triangleIndex, intersectionPoint)) {
   float intersectionDistance = distance(intersectionPoint, rayOrigin);
   if (intersectionDistance < closestIntersectionDistance) {
    closestIntersectionDistance = intersectionDistance;
    closestIntersectionPoint = intersectionPoint;
    finalColor = getTriangleColor(triangleIndex, closestIntersectionPoint);
    intersectionFound = true;
   }
  }
 }
 if (intersectionFound) {
  imageStore(outputImage, pixelCoord, vec4(finalColor, 1.0f));
 }
 else
  imageStore(outputImage, pixelCoord, vec4(0));
}
```

However when running the shader I only get 30fps. There is a significant bottleneck in the code. This is running with only 20 triangles.

What optimizations can I make to increase the performance of the code? Why is there a bottleneck?

Comment: You will definitely need to rethink your parallelization approach. With a local size of 1 its very likely that you get good results. Having a first look at it, there seems to be a lot of computation that are done more often then needed. For example, e1 and e2 are computed #pixel*#triangle times, although it's only needed #triangle times. e1 is the same as v1, but it's calculated twice. rayOrigin doesn't need to be calculated in the shader at all since it will be the same for all invocations. And I'm quite certain there is an easier way to determine the direction of the ray.

Comment: There are tons of other such things too: `inverse(proj * model)` is constant for all invocations, so pre-calculate it. If you want to go for more triangles, you will also need a acceleration structure for triangles. Writing a high performance GPU raytracer is not an easy task. There has been ~10 years of research on that.

Comment: @BDL did you mean that "with a local size of 1 its very **unlikely** that you get good results"?

Comment: @YakovGalka: Yes. Thanks for pointing it out, unfortunately, I can't edit the comment anymore.

Comment: I've added those optimizations and edited my question with the updated code. Still not receiving any major performance gains though!!

Comment: @ZeunO8 You didn't change your group size. Nor did you implement any form of an acceleration structure. The last is more important than any of the changes that you made combined. Something as simple as a BVH can bring you a long way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to more than double my framerate by making the following modifications:

**Change layout to a higher value**

for this I used `GL_MAX_COMPUTE_WORK_GROUP_INVOCATIONS`

```cpp
 GLint glMaxComputeWorkGroupInvocations = 0;
 glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_COMPUTE_WORK_GROUP_INVOCATIONS, &glMaxComputeWorkGroupInvocations);
 LIGHTING_SHADER_LOCAL_SIZE_Y = LIGHTING_SHADER_LOCAL_SIZE_X = sqrt(glMaxComputeWorkGroupInvocations);
```

and update the layout sizes:

```
layout (local_size_x = ${LIGHTING_SHADER_LOCAL_SIZE_X}, local_size_y = ${LIGHTING_SHADER_LOCAL_SIZE_Y}, local_size_z = 1) in;
```

**Get pixelCoord based on group_id and local_id**

```c
 ivec3 groupId = ivec3(gl_WorkGroupID);
 ivec3 localId = ivec3(gl_LocalInvocationID);
 ivec3 globalId = ivec3(gl_GlobalInvocationID);
 ivec3 coords = groupId * ivec3(gl_WorkGroupSize) + localId;
 ivec2 pixelCoord = ivec2(coords.xy);
```

**Update glDispatchCompute**

```
glDispatchCompute(windowWidth / LIGHTING_SHADER_LOCAL_SIZE_X, windowHeight / LIGHTING_SHADER_LOCAL_SIZE_Y, 1);
```